# change value of variable in external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external JS file that holds variables, for example:
numberToLevel.js

```
var number = 1;
```

And very simply through HTML I want to check the value and change it as the user goes through the navigation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/numberToLevel.js"></script>
    <script>
        if(number == 1){
            alert('Success!! ' + number);
        }
        number = number + 1;
    </script>
```

However, the value of `number` doesn't seem to change. the alert is triggered and it does display what it should. However, in the next page I needed it to be 2 instead of 1 and that hasn't happened.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You need to load the script as you load a new page usually. You probably need a cookie or localstorage (or sessionstorage as well.)

Comment: You have included the JavaScript script in your HTML, right? Also `localStorage` is something you'd want to consider.